# When I debug php with var_dump variable it always outputs file path at the beginning?

Tags: php, var-dump

I am using Ubuntu with PHP 7.

```
PHP 7.0.5-3+donate.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

When I debug a PHP script by using `var_dump` to show some variable:

```
<?php
var_dump('tmp string');
var_dump(true);
```

The below is its output:

```
/var/www/example.com/test.php:3:string 'tmp string' (length=10)
/var/www/example.com/test.php:4:boolean true
```

Why does it always output with the file path before?

I want it to output like below:

```
string 'tmp string' (length=10)
boolean true
```

Comment: Why do you want it to not show the file path?

Comment: This is nice feature :) Why do you want remove them?

Comment: Yes it is, but when I debug it then it will take up the extra place

Answer (score 8):

The output you're seeing is from the Xdebug extension. (Without the extension, `var_dump` outputs plain, unformatted text.)

From Xdebug 2.3, the setting `xdebug.overload_var_dump` has a new default value of `2` which adds the filename and line number to the output from any call to `var_dump`. See [the docs for more info](https://xdebug.org/docs/display). I agree it's not that useful, especially for simple output like short strings/numbers.

To remove the filename you can set the option to the old value of `1` in your php.ini file:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
```

Comment: I tried this on the php.ini file but did not work so I ended up using `ini_set("xdebug.overload_var_dump",1);` instead

Comment: @Val did you restart / reload the server after making the changes in the php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here from a search on the topic, but I continued to look for other alternatives and just wanted to add what I found for others.

As of version, Xdebug >= 2.6, there are a few options to modify the display of the file name shown in a var_dump.

```php
// real output example of the %n specifier
courses_list.php:14:string 'tools' (length=5)
```

Ref: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#filename_format

```
xdebug.filename_format = "[Specifier]"
```

> Type: string, Default value: ...%s%n, Introduced in Xdebug >= 2.6
>
> This setting determines the format with which Xdebug renders filenames in HTML stack traces (default: ...%s%n) and location information through the overloaded xdebug_var_dump() (default: %f).

- Specifier : %a

  - Meaning: Ancester: Two directory elements and filename
  - Example Output: mail/transport/mta.php
- Specifier : %f

  - Meaning: Full path
  - Example: /var/www/vendor/mail/transport/mta.php
  - *(is default setting)*
- Specifier: %n

  - Meaning: Name - Only the file name
  - Example: mta.php
- Specifier: %p

  - Meaning Parent - One directory element and the filename
  - Example: transport/mta.php
- Specifier: %s

  - Meaning: Directory separator
  - Example: \ on Linux, OSX and other Unix-like systems, / on Windows