# Why does var_dump display the file path?

Tags: php, var-dump

I'm having some problems with `var_dump`.

This is my code:

```
$rezultat = 5 < 2;
$rezultat1 = 5 > 2;
var_dump($rezultat);
echo $rezultat1;
```

And this outputs:

> C:\wamp\www\djole-php\test.php:5:boolean false 1

As you can see, `var_dump` displays the whole path before the result instead of just "boolean false".

Can I make it just show the result without the path?

Comment: how exactly you run the code?

Comment: Do you want the type as well, or just the result?

Comment: Have you tried a different dump like `print_r($rezultat);` ?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just want result without path

Comment: @Dekel I made php file in wamp>www then i run it in browser with localhost

Comment: what is the exact content of the php file?

Comment: @Dekel
<?php

 $rezultat = 5 < 2;
 $rezultat1 = 5 > 2;
 var_dump($rezultat);
 echo $rezultat1;

?>

Comment: @Machavity It shows nothing

Comment: Its not a bug/issue/problem. Its the way its supposed to work with XDEBUG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does var\_dump show filename and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375389/why-does-var-dump-show-filename-and-line-number)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because of xdebug overloading `var_dump`. If you edit your php.ini and add

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump=1
```

You will no longer get the filename and line number with `var_dump`. The default setting is 2, which includes the filename and line number with the variable info. A setting of 0 will disable the xdebug override altogether.

As far as how to update php.ini, there are [a lot of xdebug settings](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) that probably aren't defined there, and xdebug will just use their default values. So if it's not there, you can add it and it will override the default. If it *is* there, just change its value.

Where you put it doesn't matter too much. If you see any other xdebug settings, you can put it with them. If not, at the end should be fine.

---

If you just want to see the value of the variable without any other information, consider using `var_export` instead of `var_dump`.